# Windows 10 not starts my Delphi 7 program if there is no (random) argument in command line

Tags: command-line, delphi, windows-10-pro

This morning some of my clients contact me reporting that my application wasn't starting (from night to day).

After trying some things I noted a bizarre behavior:

**My application only starts if I pass some random argument to it.**

[SEE THE BUG IN THIS ANIMATED GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWuq9.jpg)

The SO is a Windows 10 PRO: Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.17763.805]

Another bizarre thing is that the Windows doesn't generate events logs about the behavior.

In other environments this doesn't occurs (other Win10 PRO, Win7, etc), it isn't a default behavior (bizarre too).

Some customers related the simple fact of "restarting" the computer has fixed the issue.

I'm in dark with this, someone has any idea?

Comment: Windows 10 build 10.0.11763.805 does not exist.

Comment: If you create a completely new program from scratch with nothing in it, just a simple "hello world" program, does that have the same behavior? If not, then there is something in your code wrong and this is something for StackOverflow.

Comment: This issue is a problem with the software itself.

Comment: @Ramhound likely yes, but not necessarily. We have to rule it out first.

Comment: @LPChip why to do this? Some windows 10 builds my program works, and other not. This starts to happen from night to day, this is why I'm so frustrated.

Comment: @Ramhound this version info I got running the command "ver" in command prompt. So, I think it exists!

Comment: @BetoNeto You have a problem that is pretty broad. In order to find out where things go wrong, you need to narrow it down.

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry, the windows version was wrong... the correct one is Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.17763.805]

Comment: That Animated `.GIF` Thingy does not show the whole screen. What are _exactly_ the Error Messages that it produces?

Comment: @BetoNeto - I knew it didn’t exist, I also knew what version you meant, I check the Windows 10 update history (how I knew)

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai there is no error message, the program simply doesn't starts... no message, no windows events registration... nothing!

Comment: @LPChip a simple "hello world" works.... but the problem is that my program uses so many features of delphi 7 framework and also a LOT of lines in my program... I'll try the get an environment and install the IDE and try to debug it to find out what is happening...

Comment: In any case, given that Hello World works, makes that this question does not belong on SuperUser, because it appears to be a programming question. You may want to try Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why should there be any kind of registrations of any kind of events? It probably does not get there. I agree with LPChip. Does the `"Hello, World?"` Tiny Little Program interact through events with the _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ Operating System? I doubt it. Just debug your Program. I thoroughly understand your frustration and your temptation to blame the _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ Operating System for absolutely everything that is happening nowadays under the Sun, but then again - it is just an Operating System.

Comment: @LPChip this morning I got access to one of this environments, and I have installed the Delphi 7 to debug it and I do not get the problem anymore. And now, after uninstall the IDE, the program starts to work correctly (bizarre).

Comment: So its missing some dependencies. Is there a Delphi runtime library? If so, you need to install it, similar to Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Runtime.